# how to remove row indicator column from datagridview in winforms c#

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Please see the attached screenshot. How do I avoid/delete the extra column marked in red? Basically this column act as a row indicator. 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the [RowHeadersVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_RowHeadersVisible) = false to hide the row header:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

> **Remarks**
>    If the RowHeadersVisible property is false, a row whose Resizable property is set to true can still be resized in the user
>   interface (UI) by clicking the mouse cursor anywhere along the bottom
>   border of the row to be resized.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could not be figured out the exact name of that header.